# Drupal hook_theme() Template Issue

Tags: blocks

I am creating a block and I cannot get it to render correctly. I need to render a list of links but it is not working and it is showing nothing on the page.

I have the `hook_theme()` function like this:

```
function list_city_theme() {
  return array(
    'list_city_display' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'title' => NULL,
        'locations' => NULL
      ),
      'template' => 'filter-by-city--display.tpl.php',
    ),
  );
}
```

And heres where i'm trying to set the theme inside the block view function:

```
$args = array(
  'title' => 'Filter by Town / City',
  'locations' => $locations
);
$block['content'] = theme('list_city_display', $args);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working for me. I have created a module called **testtheme** and mytemplate.tpl.php file is under testtheme/templates/.

Please try following sample code

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_info().
 */
function testtheme_block_info() {
  $blocks['testtheme'] = array(
    'info' => t('Test Theme'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function testtheme_block_view($delta=0) {
  $black = array();
  if ($delta == 'testtheme') {
    $block['subject'] = t('Test Theme');
    $args = array(
      'title' => 'Filter by Town / City',
      'locations' => 'Bangalore',
    );
    $block['content'] = theme('list_city_display', $args);
  }
  return $block;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function testtheme_theme() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'testtheme');
  return array(
    'list_city_display' => array(
      'variables' => array(
        'title' => NULL,
        'locations' => NULL
      ),
      'template' => 'mytemplate',
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
      'type' =>'theme',
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To View the contents in a block must be implemented [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 *@param $delta
 */
function list_city_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch($delta) {
    case 'block_name' :      
      $block['content'] = theme('list_city_display', array('result' => array('title'=> NULL,'locations' => NULL)));
      break;  
  }
  return $block;
}
```